# Realm Mongodb missing permission with HTTPS Endpoint and Function

Tags: mongodb, realm

i create  a function to insert document via https endpoint in mongodb realm.

```
exports = async function(arg){
  
  let body = arg.body.text();
  let map = JSON.parse(body);
  
  const serviceName = "mongodb-atlas";

  let database_name = map['database'];
  let collection_name = map['collection'];
  let items = map['items'];
  
  console.log(items);
  
  const collection = context.services.get(serviceName).db(database_name).collection(collection_name);

  const res = await collection.insertMany(items);
  

  return res;
};
```

function setting :
[image]

and create a rules in collection : using their preset : `readAndWriteAll` .
[image]
i believe this rule will allow read and write any operation.

but somehow the function log an error :

`role "readAndWriteAll" in "<database>.<collection>" does not have insert permission`.

**this error gone** if i use Authentication as System. what i am missing here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i was to focus on rules, in fact there is no problem with rules at all.
the extended log : `role "readAndWriteAll" in "bank_soal.tes_psikologi" does not have insert permission: could not validate document: jawaban: Invalid type. Expected: type: undefined, bsonType: int, given: [double number float mixed]`

i write the front end in dart/flutter, somehow the fuction messed with my model. the parameter `jawaban` should be int as i write in flutter, but somehow its change into `double/mixed` in mongodb function.

same with double it convert into int.

quick solution: i convert all my parameter to string. no problem in validating and even i can use custom user data to write rules : `isAdmin:true`

my vision is : its look like i must use BSON / EJSON, (i've heard before but not understand how its work) instead of raw json and sent it into api but for now, the problem is on validating json data schema. (i use GraphQL)